# Javascript Google Maps API cancelling drag event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
function makeMarkerChangeLocation(uuid, marker, poiCore){

    //checking here if drag should be allowed
    if()....

    return function(mouseEvent){
    }
}

//when placing marker programmably in map
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragstart', makeMarkerChangeLocation(uuid, marker, poiCore));
```

How can I cancel dragging or not allow to drag marker at all when my `if()` returns false?

All marker are draggable but while selecting one marker, dragging other markers should not be allowed. Maybe there is some kind of way to even check before dragging so drag would not work.